# Swoole server only can be used in PHP CLI mode

Tags: php, slim, php-7.2, swoole

I am using Swoole server and slim framework, especially this library:

[Slim Swoole Link](https://github.com/pachico/slim-swoole)

I have followed the tutorial, and gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Swoole\Server::__construct(): swoole_server only can be used in PHP CLI mode. in /Users/powermilk/Documents/Proyectos/prueba/public/index.php on line 48

the line 48 has the below code:

```
$http = new swoole_http_server("0.0.0.0", 8081);
```

I don't understand why happens this if I quit the library code everything works nice, but I am not able to run slim with Swoole.

The server is running over Nginx.

Comment: how do you start it？do you start it by cli？swoole do not support   php-fpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the writer of the library.
Yes, you have to create your "front controller"ish file and execute it from CLI.
Sort of, from terminal, "php name_of_your_file.php" and leave it running.

Comment: Okay, it tried to execute from Nginx server. One question, are you going to write a library for use sockets in slim framework?

Comment: I'm not planning it at the moment since I haven't seen a use case for me. But if you're interested and need a hand, I could help you out.